# How to avoid attachment N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, select-n-plus-1

Given

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar

  def avatar_path
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path avatar,
                                                         disposition: 'inline',
                                                         only_path: true
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

How can I avoid N+1 queries to `active_storage_attachments` and `active_storage_blobs` when trying to display each avatar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [ActiveStorage's examples](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activestorage#examples), you can use `#with_attached_A`, where `A` is the name of the attachment:

```
User.all.with_attached_avatar
```

---

Similarly, if you had many attached, you can use `#with_attached_As`.